# Get Name Device of GetLastInputInfo

Tags: c#, input

I'm a new guy here, and my English is not very good, still I hope anybody can help me.

Actually I'm using `LASTINPUTINFO` and `GetLastInputInfo` to get the inactivity of the system, but when I'm connecting a specific headsets, it generates inputs.

How I can exclude this device? Is there any way to get the name of device who generate the last input?

Or any other solution?

This is the code what I'm using:

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public struct LASTINPUTINFO
{
    public uint cbSize;
    public uint dwTime;
}
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
static extern bool GetLastInputInfo(ref LASTINPUTINFO plii);

public TimeSpan? GetInactiveTime()
{
    info = new LASTINPUTINFO();
    info.cbSize = (uint)Marshal.SizeOf(info);
    if (GetLastInputInfo(ref info))
        return TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(Environment.TickCount - info.dwTime);
    else
        return null;
}

private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    tiempoInactivity = GetInactiveTime().ToString().Substring(0,8);
    label1.Text = "Inactividad: " + tiempoInactivity;
}
```

Comment: You need to provide some code you are using to get any kind of response.

Answer (score 0):

You can disable a physical device using Hardware Helper library. It might help. If you can provide your code snippets, then it might be possible help further.
Some info is available at http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/21503/Hardware-Helper-Library-for-C

Updated- you may use rawinputdevice  to exclude a input device or to direct input to a background application instead

Comment: I can't disable it, because i need the headsets keep running all the time. Thanks for the answer.